# Hashing algorithm that meet FISMA / other federal informations systems requirements

Tags: fips

I work in an organization that must meet FISMA requirements for FIPS-enabled systems. One of the thing that I am trying to do is implement a hash algorithm for our passwords. I have many choice on this: SHA-2, MD5, bcrypt (with Blowfish), RIPE, etc.

Reading through the various NIST publication, there is NOTHING that FISMA stated that I must use a specific algorithm to meet their requirements.

However, FIPS 180-4 specifies WHICH hash algorithm is considered secure according to FISMA, which is SHA-1 to SHA-512/256. NIST SP 800-132 also recommend the use of PBKDS2.

So does this mean that:
a). I HAVE to use SHA for the hash algorithm to pass the FISMA audit / requirements?

...OR...

b). I CAN use any algorithm as long as it is BETTER than SHA? I.e. don't use MD5, but bcrypt or RIPE is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you have to use SHA.  [SP 800-53](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-53-Rev3/sp800-53-rev3-final_updated-errata_05-01-2010.pdf) references FIPS 140-2 all over the place, implying that you must use SHA-256 or SHA-512.  ([Avoid SHA-1](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/hash/policy.html)).

It's spelled out clearly in the [MEMORANDUM FOR HEADS OF EXECUTIVE DEPARTMENTS AND AGENCIES](http://www.whitehouse.gov/sites/default/files/omb/assets/memoranda_2010/m10-15.pdf) from the Executive Office of the President:

> 11. Is use of National Institute of Standards and Technology (NIST) publications
>       required?
>
> Yes. For non-national security programs and information systems, agencies
>       must follow NIST standards and guidelines. **...**
>
> 12. Are NIST guidelines flexible?
>
> Yes. While agencies are required to follow NIST standards and guidelines in
>      accordance with OMB policy, there is flexibility within NIST’s guidelines
>      (specifically in the 800-series) in how agencies apply them. **However,
>      Federal Information Processing Standards (FIPS) are mandatory. ...**

(And think about it.  NIST didn't publish SHA as a standard so that you could go and use something else instead...)

Also, SHA and Bcrypt aren't really directly comparable.  SHA is a set of hashing algorithms.  Bcrypt is more of a process to produce a hash with the Blowfish algorithm at its core.  The FIPS equivalent of Bcrypt is [PBKDF2](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/nistpubs/800-132/nist-sp800-132.pdf), which uses SHA as its core algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

How about both? Hash/salt your passwords using bcrypt to take advantage of its work factor features to provide future-proofing against massively parallel brute force attacks. Then SHA-512 the result from bcrypt and store that.

You get your protection from bcrypt, and you check the FISMA/FIPS box because you're storing a hash generated with their accepted algorithm.

Even if someone could brute-force SHA-512 to find an input that generates the same hash you've got stored in the database, that input isn't a working password that can log a user into the system.